# Why is the Microsoft Graph API webhook framework not consistent in sending notifications?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am receiving and processing notifications, but it is extremely unreliable. To paint a picture: Let's say I move 10 e-mails from the deleted folder in Outlook to the inbox. Subscribing to deleted and created updates, you'd expect 20 notifications. Depending on your (seemingly) 'luck', you instead get between 18-20 notifications. Thus missing e-mails that the hook is never notified of.

To remedy, I've set up a lifecycle webhook for missed notifications. This only triggers every so often when a message hasn't been sent and the only solution is to then perform a full sync. Which is against the idea of having a webhook.

Some of the things I've done:

- Confirmed that the notifications aren't being sent through App Insights and application logs
- Set up a Lifecycle webhook to help identify issues
- Set up working throttling and self-renewing subscriptions

At this point I'm inclined to say that the framework isn't working as intended, but I'll gladly be proven wrong.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Edit (func not being called):

```
    [FunctionName("MessageNotificationHook")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "delete", "post", "put", "patch", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
     [Queue(Routes.CommandQueue), StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")] ICollector<ImportMailMessageCommand> queueOutput,
     [Queue(Routes.CommandQueueDev), StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")] ICollector<ImportMailMessageCommand> queueOutputDev)
    {
        var validationToken = req.Query["validationToken"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken))
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"[{LOGGING_TAG}] {validationToken}");
            return new ContentResult { Content = validationToken, ContentType = "text/plain" };
        }

        logger.LogInformation($"[{LOGGING_TAG}] called.");
        // _ = Task.Run(() => ProcessNotification(queueOutput, queueOutputDev, req));

        return new AcceptedResult();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done. Should be runnable with a storage account/emulator. Can also remove the two output parameters and then it's blank.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Having a similar issue - when a message is moved we receive completely random change notifications, sometimes an update (correct/expected), sometimes a delete and create (weird but ok), sometimes create then delete (results in duplicates or missing emails). Was lifecycle webhooks the solution for you? Thanks

Comment: It wasn't, what you would have to do is poll the Graph API repeatedly for updates until your inbox was up to date again, whenever it broke. The webhook wasn't reliable and so we'd have to end up polling too often, and it didn't always notify you of the webhook failing, so the lifecycle webhook was pretty unreliable in itself. We decided to poll in intervals for updates and keep our data up to date that way instead, sans webhook.